# Use the Ratio Test to test for convergence or divergence of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{n^5}$$

I applied the Ratio Test and ended up with $[(2n+2)!(n^5)]/[(n+1)^5(2n)!]$
which I simplified down: $\lim_{n\to\infty}2n^5(2n+1)/(n+1)^4 = \infty > 1$ so it diverges

Is this correct? (Sorry about the formatting)

Comment: It is correct (minus the formatting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but a very big gun for this series. Note that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{n^5}=\infty
$$
and all convergent series must have the limit of their terms tend to $0$ (although beware, this is no guarantee).